# Org-mode+Babel: Refactor across files or code blocks

Tags: org-mode, refactoring

I'm refactoring my Emacs config files so that they are generated with [org-babel-tangle](https://orgmode.org/manual/Extracting-Source-Code.html). I am able to do everything I need but I really miss better refactoring support.

As an example, after I define a symbol (variable, function), there maybe a lot of unrelated code and prose before the next usage:

> Some explanation about `a` and `x`:
>
> ```
> (defun a ...)
> (defvar x ...)
> ```
>
> Another paragraph ...
>
> ```
> ((((more))))(((lisp)))()()((((code)))
> ```
>
> Using `a` or `x`:
>
> ```
> (doSomething (a) ...)
> (crashSystem x ...)
> ```

To rename a symbol, I enter [edit mode (`C-c '`)](https://orgmode.org/manual/Editing-Source-Code.html), and there is some limited refactoring support, e.g., rename symbol, extract variable, etc. However, changes to a symbol across all Babel blocks or across files is not supported.

My workflow today is to use `helm-projectile-ag` to find usages in the project (git repo) and then apply the required changes to each, one by one, by hand.

I have been googling for refactoring support across blocks/files so far with little success. I have posted this question to gather some pointers, references to Emacs packages that can improve my refactoring workflow or maybe help me rethink my workflow.